# Using AMPScript to output Current Month or following Month dependent on the day of the month in a Marketing Cloud Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to have AMPScript in a Marketing Cloud email to output a month depending on the day of month from a date field in a data extension?

Eg: if the day is <=19 (say 15 May) of the month show current Month (May), >=20 (say 23 May) of the month show following month (June).

Im guessing it needs a range included: Based on if the email is being sent in May the calculation would be based on:

(>=20 April to <= 19 May) Show May
(>=20 May to <= 19 June) Show June

We need to this to let people know when they will be billed on their account

I have a data extension called (BillingSetup) that has a CreatedDate which i would like to use to make the calculation but have no idea where to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can probably handle this with some [**DatePart**](https://ampscript.guide/datepart/) and [**DateAdd**](https://ampscript.guide/dateadd/) footwork.  Something like below:

```
%%[
SET @date = NOW()
SET @currentDay = DatePart(@date,"D")

IF @currentDay < 20 THEN
   SET @month = DatePart(@date,"monthName")
ELSE
   SET @month = DatePart(DateAdd(@date,1,"M"),"monthName")
ENDIF
]%%

%%=v(@month)=%%
```

This will output current month is day is lower than 20, but if the day is 20 or higher, it will output the next month.

**E.g.** 
If date is 8/7/2020, it would output:
`August`

If date is 8/20/2020, it would output:
`September`

You would just adjust the value filling `@date` to your lookup or attributevalue() call. You would need to make sure that the date you are pulling in is actually formatted as a date, or it will cause issues. If you need to format your value, try using **[FormatDate](https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/)**.

---

**EDIT**
With [**DateAdd**](https://ampscript.guide/dateadd/) as requested in comments:

```
%%[
SET @date = NOW()
SET @date = DateAdd(@date, 18, "H")
SET @currentDay = DatePart(@date,"D")

IF @currentDay < 20 THEN
   SET @month = DatePart(@date,"monthName")
ELSE
   SET @month = DatePart(DateAdd(@date,1,"M"),"monthName")
ENDIF
]%%

%%=v(@month)=%%
```

This will now set it to 18 hours 'in the future' of server time.  If you need it to be adjusted to 18 hours prior, you just change it to `-18` and that will adjust accordingly.

If you noticed in my DateAdd, I have the 3rd Parameter as `'H'` this is representing that hours are what will be adjusted. You had an `'M'` there which means it would have been 18 months added on.

If you need help learning, I would highly recommend utilizing **[AMPScript.Guide](https://ampscript.guide)** and other similar resources (There are great articles and information at [**HowToSFMC.com**](https://howtosfmc.com) as well as a good list of other resources that can be accessed for information, including blogs, videos, etc.) as well as the **[Email-Geeks](https://email.geeks.chat/)** Slack channel (which has a SFMC channel or two.

Comment: Thanks @gortonington, the only challenge i have is we have a 18hr time difference so need to do Dateadd (i think), I tried this but my AMPScript skills are lacking

` %%[ SET @date = DateAdd(now(), '18','h') 
         SET @currentDay = DatePart(@date,"D") 
         IF @currentDay <20 THEN SET 
         SET @month = DatePart(@date,"monthName") 
         ELSE SET @month = DatePart(DateAdd(@date,1,"M"),"monthName") ENDIF ]%%

         %%=v(@month)=%% `

Comment: @Andyw - Edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks @gortonington, I can see the changes however i get an error " Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid<br>The variable name is not a valid because it is of zero length. Variable names must begin with the @ symbol followed by one or more letters, numbers, or underscores. Variable Name:". I copied your exact code to make sure there is no HTML Code breaking it and its in a stand alone content block for testing. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it was likely because I didn't put a space in the comparison and had it be `<20` when it should have been `< 20`. Try it now

Comment: Its still not happy, same error @gortonington

Comment: Found it. I had a duplicate 'SET' after the first if statement. Apologies! Should work now

Comment: Thanks very much @gortonington worked perfect now